# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory + os.execv

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, argparse

I am creating a wrapper script to execute my python programs. The logic is like:

1. I will install all my required modules in a docker container
2. Pull the container and run the script, so anyone can run my scripts without worrying about the depended modules
3. I created a wrapper script that will be called to execute the desired program

This is my wrapper script:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parse.add_argument('command', help="give datacenter name")
parse.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
parse_arguments = parse.parse_args()

'''
Co-relate to the command and corresponding scripts to trigger
'''
scripts = {
    'verify' : '/path/verify.py'
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if parse_arguments.command not in scripts:
        print('These are the available scripts to run:')
        print('\n'.join(sorted(scripts.keys())))
    else:
        os.execv(scripts.get(parse_arguments.command), 
[scripts.get(parse_arguments.command)] + parse_arguments.args) .
```

I am running this like,

```
$ docker run -it --rm --net host run-script verify --listenv tpc1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/runme.py", line 28, in <module>
    os.execv(scripts.get(parse_arguments.command), 
[scripts.get(parse_arguments.command)] + parse_arguments.args)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My Docker image is run-script

If I run the same code from my local machine, it does work. but inside container it shows this file not find error.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to `sys.argv` is the path to the running file, here `/path/runme.py`. The file is found when run from your local machine, but probably not in the docker container (I'm not sure why).

Try to set the [prog parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog) when instanciating your ArgParser, something like:

```
parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="run_me.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue. The issue was mainly with the shebang that I have provided. So when I was executing the script in the docker container, it was checking to execute code from shebang location.

I would say, that is a mistake from my side, FileNotFoundError was not giving me a clue to shebang. Finally, figured it out.

@olinox14 - Thanks for your update, "prog" parameter in argparse helped me to output a better help message with the script name in docker container, rather than the full path inside docker container.

Answer (score 0):

`os.execv(program, args)` by default doesn't search for **program** (first argument) based on PATH envrionment variable. `os.execvp` does.

From [`os.execv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execv) :

> `os.execv(path, args)`
>
> The variants which include a “p” near the end (execlp(), execlpe(),
>   execvp(), and execvpe()) will use the PATH environment variable to
>   locate the program file.

So, either user `os.execvp` or provide full path to program to be run to `os.execv`.